# How to insert comma after each element in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector with 4225 elements that its elements are separated by spaces and I have to use this vector in MuPAD as edge weight matrix of a directed graph. In order to make this vector accessible in MuPAD as a graph edge weight matrix, its elements should be separated by commas. Since the number of elements is huge, it's a waste of time to write commas between them one by one. So is there any simple way to do this in matlab?

Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

```
%// example vector
a = [4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13];

%// replace all consecutive spaces with a comma
aCSV = regexprep(num2str(a,17), '\s*', ',')
```

Output:

```
aCSV = 
    4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
```

Comment: Be aware that `num2str` converts floating point values to a string with four digits of accuracy by default.

Comment: @horchler: strange...the documentation indeed mentions 4 digits, but `num2str(v)` on your `v` works like a charm...Edited my answer nonetheless

Comment: I think that `num2str(v)` for my demo data printed out more digits because of the presence of `realmax`. If that element is not present, it reverts to printing only up to four decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version using only [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
v = [1 2 exp(1) 3 pi 4 5 realmax];
s = sprintf('%.17g,',v); % Up to 17 decimal places (double precision has about 16) 
s = s(1:end-1);          % Remove trailing comma
```

This returns

```
s =

1,2,2.7182818284590455,3,3.1415926535897931,4,5,1.7976931348623157e+308
```

See [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) for details on using format strings with `sprintf` if you wish to further customize this.